# Mean absolute distance for a symmetric random walk

Tags: random, random-walk

I have found that the mean absolute distance for a symmetric random walk
after n steps can be computed using this product:

[image: MAD]

What can be deduced from this?

For example how can variance be computed using this formula?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are referring to by "mean absolute distance."? Is it as defined in (22.2) in this paper? https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/718277.JHizakRLogozar_ADerivationOfMeanAbsDistancIn1DRndmWalk.pdf I ask because there several measures of statistical dispersion (mean absolute difference, mean absolute deviation, etc.) with which one might get this confused (seeing as the acronyms are the same.

Comment: I'm refering to distance from origin.

Comment: Yes, The mean absolute distance (MAD) 
. This product is equivalent to the sum given in (22,2)